# how to give horizontal and vertical header fixed but data should move

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I tried to develop table with fixed header(*i.e Header must contain - vertical and horizontal way*).

- table should be in scrollable
- table must have horizontal header
- vertical header same as horizontal header.
- when we going **up-down** using scroll header should be visible at top.(when we moving up down left side header should be up down)
- and when we scrolling **left-right** header should be visible at left side (when we moving left-right top header should be move)

**UPDATE**:
This Image is what i want in phonegap using html or any web developing tools. **BUT NOT in EXCEL**

[image: Image is here]

---

This table i am developing for my mobile app(Android/iPhone) etc.

I have seen many table but i am not able to find my perfect way.
I am using **phoneGap**, **jqueryMobile**, **jQuery**, **html**, **css**, **javascript**, third party **.js** and other web search...

Thanks and sorry for my grammar.

Comment: So you essentially want it to act like excel's row and column labels?

Comment: see my **update** for more detail, sorry for that..

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear... I was asking if you wanted it to "act like" Excel's row/column labels... not be in excel.  I was just using Excel as an example to see if I understood your intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi check this jsfiddle this may help you  working example  http://bit.ly/1flXtbs

Answer (score 2):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T7CuL/)

One way to solve this is to use css for horizontal and vertical headers by using div layout and applying `position: fixed;` and then design you tabular data using table layout as you want and by applying the top and left margin for them.

But it's not possible if you want exactly as Microsoft's Excel with **this solution**.

Comment: this seems good but i want table if it is possible.
and both Header should move as per my Que.